# Error in send verification mail in laravel5.7

Tags: laravel-5.7

I'm trying to send email in my application, but i'm getting the following error

**swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond.**

My configration in ".env" is as follows

```
**MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail`enter code here`
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME='vishalsundriyal567@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD="vishal@123"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls**
```

Answer (score 0):

this is Connection problem
recheck this login gmail data and stm url and port 
or show how yo set this .env to Connection Gmail

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=addYourEmail

MAIL_PASSWORD=AddYourEmailPassword

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and make route

```
Route::get('send-main', 'HomeController@sendMail');
```

and controller for Testing

```
public function sendMail()

{

$data['title'] = "Test it from HDTutu.com";

Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function($message) {

    $message->to('aatmaninfotech@gmail.com', 'Receiver Name')

            ->subject('HDTuto.com Mail');

});

dd("Mail Sent successfully");


}
```